# Change kube-apiserver parameters

Tags: linux, docker, oauth, kubernetes

I'm trying to change kube-apiserver parameters in order to accomplish oauth based cluster login. It's possible to change parameters manually, by entering into kube-apiserver container, but it will be hard to implement that during cluster spawn. Do you have suggestions or existing solutions for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This massively depends on what you're using to provision the cluster - are you using a well-known provisioner or your own custom solution?

Comment: i'm using own script which is combination of kops, aws-cli and kops, but basically it's kops doing cluster spawn.

Comment: kops exposes fields for configuring OIDC authentication on the apiserver https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_spec.md#kubeapiserver - is the sort of thing you're after?

Answer (score 0):

kops exposes apiserver fields that can be used to configure [OIDC authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication#openid-connect-tokens). The documentation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_spec.md#kubeapiserver) describes the format